# getting a SSL error when i run python script to connect to Sql server

Tags: python, pyodbc

I am getting the below error when i run my python code to connect to sql server.

`pyodbc.OperationalError: ('08001', '[08001] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][DBMSLPCN]SSL Security error (18) (SQLDriverConnect); [08001] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][DBMSLPCN]ConnectionOpen (SECCreateCredentials()). (1)'`

The code is use is

```
`
import pyodbc
conn = pyodbc.connect('Driver={SQL Server};Server=Dev-SQL-01\INST00;Database=mydb;'
                  'Trusted_Connection=yes;')
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM Table1')

for row in cursor:
  print(row)`
```

Need your input

Comment: what all things you have tried to resolve this already? Cold you update the question with them?

Comment: One update ...this was due to TLS setting issue. Microsoft OLE DB was not working properly